# ASP.NET - Is it possible to render a TreeViewControl as an unordered list instead of a table?

Tags: asp.net, list, treeview, controls, unordered

Is it possible to render a TreeViewControl as an unordered list instead of a table?

Answer (score 1):

you'd be better off using a recursive loop. the TreeViewControl is not a light-weight control by any means.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET now allows ControlAdapters, that you can write and completely change the way control appear on the page. You can try writing your own adapter for TreeViewControl.